# The output of this is 3 can anybody tell me how?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
int main()
{

    long int a = scanf("%ld %ld %ld",&a,&a,&a);
    printf("%ld",a);
    return 0;   
}
```

The output of this is 3 can anybody tell me how?

Comment: You forget to provide a input example that correspond to your output example.

Comment: use "42 41 forty" as input, or "half a dozen".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the manual of [`scanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

> Return Value
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.

So like you want that `scanf()` parse 3 `long int`, it can return `EOF`, `0`, `1`, `2` or `3`.

By the way, the type of return of `scanf()` is `int`, not `long int`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long int al, bl, cl;
    int ret = scanf("%ld %ld %ld", &al, &bl, &cl);
    printf("ret = %d:", ret);
    if (ret == 3) {
        printf(" al = %ld, bl = %ld, cl = %ld\n", al, bl, cl);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After `scanf` is finished with using `&a` and doing its work, the return value of `scanf` is assigned to `a` which can be `3` if the input starts with three whitespace seperated integral numbers.

The return value is the number of the successfully matched and assigned input items.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking 3 items as input, even though you are collecting all inputs from scanf in a, at last it is going to hold the return value of scanf, which is number of items successfully read

In your perticular run, 3 items were successfully read so a holds 3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Pras is correct.  Since you (apparently) successfully read three value from the input, the return value from scanf is three.  But it is *very* bad programming practice to use the set the value of the same variable more than once in a single statement.  In this example, you set the value of "a" *four* times, three as a result of scanf'ing from the input, and the fourth as the assignment of the return value.  If you had not assigned a to be the return value from the call, the value of "a" would be unpredictable, since the order that arguments are processed is implementation dependent.  If you typed in "11 22 33", "a" could be 11 or 33... or even 22, depending on how your compiler handles scanf.